# Using tokens in Soundcloud API to stay logged in

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I'm trying to setup a small website where you sign in with your soundcloud account. I managed to get the login working and reading different info about the logged in user. However, as soon as I switch the website, I need to log in again. I haven't worked with tokens before but as far as I know they're for having your credentials stored in a string for soundcloud to authenticate the user without logging in again.

I'm working with PHP but everything I've done so far was with javascript. Here's the code:

This is the part where I log in:

```
<script>
function signIn(){
    SC.initialize({
          client_id: "myclientid",
          redirect_uri: "http://localhost/Main/callback.html",
        });

    SC.connect(function () {
          SC.get("/me", function (response) {
            console.log("Welcome " + response.full_name);
            console.log(SC.accessToken());
            $("#name").html("Hello " + response.full_name);
          });
    });
}
</script>

<h1><span id="name"></span></h1>
<div onclick=signIn() id="SignIn">Sign In</div>
```

And as soon as I jump into this part, it gives me a "401 (Unauthorized)" because I haven't logged in on this page.

```
<script>
function getTracks(){
    SC.initialize({
      client_id: "myclientid",
      redirect_uri: "http://localhost/Main/callback.html",
    });
    var tracks = {};
    SC.get("/me/tracks", function (resp) {
        for (var i=0; i< resp.length; i++) {
            if(resp[i].downloadable){
                $("#tracklist ul").append("<li><form action=\"tracks.php\"\><input type=\"submit\" value=\""+resp[i].title+"\"></form></li>");
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>

<div onclick=getTracks() id="tracklist">
    <h3>Your Tracks:</h3>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

How do I need to use my requests with tokens?

Thanks a lot for your time in advance!
cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this works now because I've tried this before. For every request there needs to be the SC object initialized. So all I needed to do was adding this:

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: "myclientid",
  redirect_uri: "http://localhost/Main/callback.html",
  access_token: "theusersaccesstoken"
});
```

I don't know why this worked today, but finally I got it to work.